# how to prevent focus element in shadow root remove user's selection in host page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, shadow-dom

Is it possible that shadown-root can work like iframe which has an isolate env. Currently, in shadow-root, it behaviors like this:

1. user selection text on host page
2. user click an text input and focus on the input which belongs to shadow-root
3. selection text will be removed, and input will be focused.

what I hope is:

1. at least, user click input in shadow-root will not remove the selection.
2. whatever user do in shadow, will not effect the selection of host page.

Comment: No, focus wise shadowRoot content is part of the whole page.

Comment: yes, i see that. This is why i ask, hope there maybe some special tricks can do it.

Comment: Web Components with shadowRoot are no different from ``<input>`` , ``<textarea>`` and the lot. They all have shadowRoots too (see with DevTools), we in UserLand can't access those "User-Agent" shadowRoots. When we say Web Components are _like_ IFRAMES we mean styling; but even that comparison has flaws because inheritable styles do style shadowRoots (color, font etc.)

Comment: thank you, so, it seems it's imposible due the mechanism. i will close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After search and test, AFAIK it's imposible to do what i want. Just use `iframe` to wrap the input element.